# Why does my 'overflow: hidden' does not work properly?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm new to CSS, and there is a problem bothering me for a while now.
I set "overflow: hidden" on the parrent span of the img tag for a scale effect, but when I move my mouse on the image, the image will flows down to the bottom, it only hides the other 3 sides.
My code stuck in here, could someone help me out please?
Thank you so much.
here is my code:

```
<style>
.newl {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.newb {
    display: list-item;
    max-width: 23%;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.newb a {
    padding: 0 0 25px;
}
.newj img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.newj img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.newt {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
.newp {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<section class="newitem">
    <ul class="newl">
        <li class="newb">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="newj"><img src="img/new1.jpg" alt="#">
                </span>
                <span class="newt">TEST</span>
                <span class="newp">testing</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: You have set the `overflow: hidden` on the `.newb` class which is your list item. And you have not set any `overflow: hidden` on the `.newj` which is the actual image wrapper. So when the image is scaled on hover it get over the other elements in you list item.

Comment: @Emech thank you so much! looks like I still got a lot to learn about CSS, I'm really appreciate for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add position: relative and overflow: hidden, to image wrap element (in your case is .newj). Add it to your css code:

```
.newj {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: `position: relative` is not necessary.

Comment: its nessesry for ie10

Comment: thank you so much! so the ```overflow: hidden``` in the ```li``` element (newb) new is unnecessary? it seems does not hava any effect to the code. thanks again!